# PHP - Checking Character Type and Length and Trimming Leading Zeros

Tags: php, string

I have this code that works well, just inquiring to see if there is a better, shorter way to do it:

```
$sString = $_GET["s"];

if (ctype_digit($sString) == true) {
    if (strlen($sString) == 5){
        $sString = ltrim($sString, '0');
    }
}
```

The purpose of this code is to remove the leading zeros from a search query before passing it to a search engine if it is 5 digits and.  The exact scenario is A) All digits, B) Length equals 5, and C) It has leading zeros.

Better/Shorter means in execution time...

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to do *exactly*? Do we need to replicate exact behaviour? So when 6 digits are entered we leave `$sString` intact? How do you want to handle exponents (`e`) or negatives etc.? A simple `if (preg_match('/^\d{5}$/', $sString)) {` might do...

Comment: Now you've added the 2 paragraphs after your code: B) What happens with 1, 2, 4, 6, 28 digits? Keep in tact? About the better/shorter == execution time: Why would you care? Is this 'conversion' done thousands of times in a tight loop? The effects of (micro!)optimizing this will be negligable in most, if not all, cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sString = $_GET["s"];

if (preg_match('/^\d{5}$/', $sString)) {
    $sString = ltrim($sString, '0');
}
```

This is shorter (and makes some assumptions you're [not clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21866675/php-checking-character-type-and-length-and-trimming-leading-zeros#comment33105996_21866675) about in your question). However, shorter is **not always** better. Readability is sacrificed here, as well as some performance I guess (which will be negligable in a single execution, could be "costly" when run in tight loops though) etc. You ask for a "*better, shorter way to do it*"; then you need to define "better" and "shorter". Shorter in terms of lines/characters of code? Shorter in execution time? Better as in more readable? Better as in "most best practices" applied?

## Edit:

So you've added the following:

> The purpose of this code is to remove the leading zeros from a search
>   query before passing it to a search engine if it is 5 digits and. The
>   exact scenario is A) All digits, B) Length equals 5, and C) It has
>   leading zeros.

A) Ok, that clears things up (You sure characters like '+' or '-' won't be required? I assume these 'inputs' will be things like (5 digit) invoicenumbers, productnumbers etc.?)

B) What to do on inputs of length 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, ... 28? 97? Nothing? Keep input intact?

> Better/Shorter means in execution time...

Could you explain why you'd want to "optimize" this tiny piece of code? Unless you run this thousands of times in a tight loop the effects of optimizing this will be negligible. *(Mumbles something about [premature, optimization, root, evil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize))*. What is it that you're hoping to "gain" in "optimizing" this piece of code?

I haven't profiled/measured it yet, but my (educated) guess is that my `preg_match` is more 'expensive' in terms of execution time than your original code. It *is* "shorter" in terms of code though (but see above about sacrificing readability etc.).

Long story short: this code is not worth optimizing*; any I/O, database queries etc. will "cost" a hundred, maybe even thousands of times more. Go optimize that first

<sub>* Unless you have "optimized" everything else as far as possible (and even then, a database query might be more efficient when written in another way so the execution plan is mor eefficient or I/O might be saved using (more) caching etc. etc.). The fraftion of a millisecond (at best) you're about to save optimizing this code better be worth it! And even then you'd probably need to consider switching to better hardware, another platform or other programming language for example.</sub>

## Edit 2:

I have *quick'n'dirty* "profiled" your code:

```
$start = microtime(true);

for ($i=0; $i<1000000;$i++) {
  $sString = '01234';
  if (ctype_digit($sString) == true) {
    if (strlen($sString) == 5){
      $sString = ltrim($sString, '0');
    }
  }
}

echo microtime(true) - $start;
```

Output: `0.806390047073`
So, that's 0.8 seconds for **1 million(!)** iterations. My code, "profiled" the same way:

```
$start = microtime(true);

for ($i=0; $i<1000000;$i++) {
  $sString = '01234';
  if (preg_match('/^\d{5}$/', $sString)) {
    $sString = ltrim($sString, '0');
  }
}

echo microtime(true) - $start;
```

Output: `1.09024000168`
So, it's slower. As I guessed/predicted.

<sub>Note my explicitly mentioning "quick'n'dirty": for good/accurate profiling you need better tools and if you *do* use a poor-man's profiling method like I demonstrated above then at least make sure you average your numbers over a few dozen runs etc. to make sure your numbers are consistent and reliable.</sub>

But, either solution takes, worst case, less than 0,0000011 to run. If this code runs "Tens of Thousands of times a day" (assuming 100.000 times) you'll save exactly 0.11 seconds **over an entire day IF you got it down to 0!** If this 0.11 seconds is a problem you have a bigger problem at hand, not these few lines of code. It's just not worth "optimizing" (hell, it's not even worth discussing; the time you and I have taken going back-and-forth over this will not be "earned back" in at least 50 years).

Lesson learned here:
**[Measure / Profile before optimizing!](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ProfileBeforeOptimizing)**

Comment: Strings that don't match the scenario should just remain the same.

Comment: It will be ran Tens of Thousands of times a day, just trying to make it as optimal as possible.

Comment: See my second edit. It's just not worth optimizing (hell, it's not even worth discussing; the time you and I have taken posting about this will not be "earned back" in at least 50 years)

Comment: Do you by chance know how I could do this exact same thing in javascript?  Searches come in from a couple of different places, one of those is using javascript to pass the string.  I can't modify it as it comes in to the search engine, so that is off limits.  I'm forced to make these modifications in the middle between the client and and the search engine.

Comment: Why bother "offloading" the "load" to the client using JS? [You will **still** need to do it server-side](https://www.google.com/search?q=never+trust+user+input). **NEVER TRUST USER INPUT**. Clients can disable JS, or even simply change the values in the URL since you're using `$_GET`; even when you'd be using `$_POST` malicious users could easily modify values sent. I'm really trying hard to not say this (take this as well intended advise): you might want someone with a bit more experience have a look at your project because I 'smell' a few "beginner" mistakes that are bound to cause trouble.

Comment: Having said that; it probably won't hurt (in this, very specific(!), case) when you do this client-side only. The worst that would (probably!) happen is that incorrect search-results would be returned affecting only the "malicious user". Just remember that 99.999% of the time you want to do server-side validation, client-side validation is good for UX improvement (quick feedback etc.) and such things, (almost) *never* a substitute for server-side validation. It wouldn't be hard to write this code in JS; give it a try and if you fail: open a new StackOverflow question :-)

Answer (score 0):

A little shorter:

```
if (ctype_digit($sString) && strlen($sString) == 5) {
        $sString = ltrim($sString, '0');
}
```

It also matters if you want *"digits"* 0-9 or a *"numeric value"*, which may be -1, +0123.45e6, 0xf4c3b00c, 0b10100111001 etc.. in which case use `is_numeric`.

I guess you could also just do this to remove 0s:

```
$sString = (int)$sString;
```

Comment: "*I guess you could also just do* `(int)$sString;`": You *could* but you *would*, as a side-effect, change the variables type to `int` so either change the variable-name to something other than `$sString` or keep it as a string and use a construct like `ltrim(..., '0');` (IMHO). Having said that: [Hungarian Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) is [not my cup of tea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation#Disadvantages) anyway; I'd advise to avoid it **or** make sure you use it with a [good reason](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html).